# How can I get a list of other Azure Active Directory organizations I'm a Guest User of using an API eg, Graph

Tags: azure, api, graph

I want to be able to list the external Azure Active Directory organizations which my users are Guests of using an API call.

I can see this information readily in the the Azure Portal but so far cannot see how to get it from Microsoft Graph API

[Organizations List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5zhp.png)

Hope somebody has solved this please

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Sure -  for instance regarding Microsoft Teams it is easy to get a list of external Guest users in my organizations teams.  However, if I want to see what external organizations my users are Guests in this is not very clear to me how I would get such a list with an API call to MS Graph or Azure AD.        I know the information is there as I can see this in Azure AD.            Does that  explain a bit better ?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all Azure AD instances for your user using the **tenants list** endpoint:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)

If you have the Azure CLI installed, you can check it using:

```
az rest --uri https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2020-01-01 --method get
```

Comment: Thanks very much Martin for your help.    I had a look at that endpoint but unfortunately it only brings back the tenants for my own account which of course is what it is meant to do.   I wonder if you have any ideas on how I could get this information for other users in my tenant via such a REST api call - maybe its not possible.?      Thanks again for your generous suggestions.  Regards Liam

Comment: @LiamO'Neill Hi Liam, It is just my opinion and I might be wrong, but I doubt that this is possible because this would expose sensitive data, right? However, depending on what you are trying to achieve, you can write an application that gets this information on behalf of a user, after he signed in to your app. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user).

Comment: Hi Martin - I think you are right - thanks for the link to the document and for all your help. Regards  Liam

Comment: @LiamO'Neill You are welcome, wish you good luck with your requirement. Please consider accepting the answer if you think it could be helpful for others. Best - Martin